# Referencing a list of shapes from other classes

Tags: c#

I want to be able to refer to the list and see all the methods as well as change the contents of the list from other classes.

Here is the declaration:

```
public partial class TestSheet : UserControl
{
    public ShapeCollection _shapes = new ShapeCollection();
}
```

This is the ShapeCollection class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Manages a collection of shape objects
/// </summary>
public class ShapeCollection : CollectionBase
{
    public void Add(Shape s)
    {
        List.Add(s);
    }

    public void Remove(Shape s)
    {
        List.Remove(s);
    }

    public Shape this[int index]
    {
        get { return (Shape)List[index]; }
        set { List[index] = value; }
    }
}
```

I can refer to _shapes by using:

```
this._shapes.Add(s);
```

or:

```
foreach (Shape s in this._shapes)
{
     //some code
}
```

or by index on the form:

```
Shape shp;
shp = (Shape)testSheet1._shapes[TestSheet.selectedShapeNumber];
```

The only classes that can reference _shapes is the form the UserControl is on and the UserControl itself.
How do I declare _shapes differently so that _shapes can be referenced and manipulated in other classes. I am stumped. And I know it is probably something simple. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration is correct.  The problem is where you are declaring it. As is, `_shapes` is a member of of your `TestSheet`.  If you want your collection to be accessible from other locations, you should move the declaration elsewhere, for instance as a member of your form (instead of the control).  That way, any class that has a reference to your form can reference it via

```
myform._shapes.Add(s);
```

Remember, this is for if you want the same collection to be accessible by multiple `TestSheet`s per form.  If you want a separate collection per `TestSheet`, then keep what you have now

Comment: OK. So the declaration should be elsewhere. I was fixated on keeping the the usercontrol code intact since I have not coded much with UserControl's until this program. Your suggestion makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a reference to _shape to other classes or pass a reference to its container (TestSheet) to other classes.

Something like this:

```
public class Manipulator {
    private ShapeCollection shapes;

    public Manipulator(ShapeCollection shapes) {
        this.shapes = shapes;
    }

    public void doSomethingToShapes() {
        shapes.add(...);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestSheet testSheet = new TestSheet();
    Manipulator manipulator = new Manipulator(testSheet._shapes);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good code example. This helped me out a lot. Thank you.